# javaFX FXML, populating TableView using Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, javafx, tableview, fxml

I want to display in TableView, data from a class "**Etudiant**"
we call the method "**show**()" to fetch data into the tableview.

The class **Etudiant** has **String** properties, **not** **SimpleStringProperty**

So how can I populate my tableView ?
Controller:

```
@FXML
TableView<Enseignant> tableau;

@FXML
TableColumn ID;

@FXML
TableColumn<Enseignant, String> NOM;

@FXML
TableColumn PRENOM;

@FXML
ComboBox<String> matiereCB;

void show(){     
    ObservableList<Enseignant> e = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
//em : EnseignantModel : the model of this class
//show : the method that brings data in a vector
    Vector<Enseignant> enseignants = em.show();
    Enseignant enseignant = new Enseignant();
    for (int i = 0; i < enseignants.size(); i++) {
        enseignant = enseignants.get(i);
        e.add(enseignant);                        
    }
    tableau.setItems(e);
}
```

FXML:

```
<TableView fx:id="tableau" layoutX="387.0" layoutY="177.0" prefHeight="361.0" prefWidth="734.0">
    <columns>
        <TableColumn fx:id="ID" prefWidth="43.0" text="ID" />
        <TableColumn fx:id="NOM" prefWidth="95.0" text="NOM" />
        <TableColumn fx:id="PRENOM" prefWidth="94.0" text="PRENOM" />
        <TableColumn fx:id="MATIERE" prefWidth="97.0" text="Matière" />
    </columns>
</TableView>
```

Enseignant:

```
public class Enseignant  implements java.io.Serializable {

   private Integer idEnseignant;
   private String nom;
   private String prenom;
```

Comment: What is the issue? I can see that you haven't set the `cellValueFactory` for the columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should set `cellValueFactory` for each column in your table.

```
public class EnseignantFxmlController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private TableView<Enseignant> tableau;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn ID;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn NOM;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn PRENOM;


    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        //each cellValueFactory has been set according to the member variables of your entity class
        ID.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Enseignant, Integer>("idEnseignant"));
        NOM.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Enseignant, String>("nom"));
        PRENOM.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Enseignant, String>("prenom"));
        tableau.setItems(getEnseignant());
    }

  //here you can add all your Enseignants into a ObservableList
    public ObservableList<Enseignant> getEnseignant() {
        ObservableList<Enseignant> enseignantList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        Session session = util.HibernateUtil.
                getSessionFactory().openSession();
        List<Enseignant> eList = session.
                createCriteria(Enseignant.class).list();
        for (Enseignant ent : eList) {
            enseignantList.add(ent);
        }
        return enseignantList;
    }

  }
```

Comment: then should type of the fields of entity class be string or stringproperty